# Using Kamailio for Push To Talk Android App

Tags: android, sip, voip, kamailio

I installed Kamailio, am able to add users and make calls, but I need to use it for my android push to talk client app i.e. upon calling another user(s) (using the same app), instead of ringing their app/phone it should directly transmit voice of the caller while the other user(s) is muted and to respond other user presses a toggle button to speak to the caller. 
Is there a module that does this, would I have to implement my own or would I have to modify the source code to achieve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Kamailio is a SIP signaling server, usually acting as a proxy, it does not process media (audio) at all. Sending/receiving the media in a call is a matter of end points. Therefore the PTT functionality has to be implemented by client applications or a dedicated PTT server has to be placed in the network.

Comment: I installed Kamailio and used Jitsi to make calls through the Kamailio installation. So are you suggesting that I with Jitsi source code to implement push to talk functionality which will work with Kamailio's SIP signalling? Thanks.